# TypeError: member.guild.channels.get is not a function

Tags: discord.js

What can I do to fix the "TypeError: member.guild.channels.get is not a function"

```
client.on('guildMemberRemove', member => {
member.guild.channels.get('692319439542157435').send('**' + member.user.username + '**, has left the server');
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I migrate my code to Discord.js v12 from v11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`member.guild.channels.cache.get('692319439542157435')` for discord v12.

```js
client.on('guildMemberRemove', member => {
    member.guild.channels.cache.get('692319439542157435').send('**' + member.user.username + '**, has left the server');
})
```